# Macro If Statement Column Replace Current Date with Tomorrows Date

Tags: excel, replace, vba

I have Column A which has the current Date and Column B that has either "0" or "1".

I would like to make a macro where it has an if statement that if column B = "1" it would push out the Date in Column A by one day.  I would assume by using the replace function

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as integers, so all you have to do is increment the cell:

```
Sub a()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        If .Cells(1, 2).Value = 1 Then
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = .Cells(1, 1).Value + 1
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Will it loop all the way down to 25? Also is there a way for it iunstead of recognizing 1 if it said tomorrow?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.